# How to create a field that shows a number in an app and can be changed by admin

Tags: android, ios

First of all thanks for thinking with me!

I am new in making apps and need to make an one page mobile app. The app needs a field in the middle with a number, the number in that field needs to be changed by an admin so visitors can see the status (the number represents the status). Anyone an idea to fix this?

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a web service which will be fetching that number from server,
also you have to setup a mechanism through which admin can set the number for app users.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. Any suggestions in how to set up the mechanism to set the number?

Comment: No I have nothing build yet.

Comment: You need a back-end for your app to store data which can be shared among your user and admin apps. Depending upon the current and future requirements you may choose among many options available i.e. develop a custom backend for your app in PHP or .net or any other. or there are https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/ and other similar services known as mobile backend as a service.